# how to make amount thing in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

alrighty so basically i had a spam ping command that i made and i wanted to make it with an amoutn like this

```
     @commands.command(
    name="ping",
    description="boom boom boom",
    usage="<user> <amount>",
)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def ping(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, amount=15):

    if amount is None:
        await ctx.send('listen here bud your lucky this exists but your the reason that theres instuctions on conditioner bottles, specify a user')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}"+amount)
```

butthat doesnt work and i know i messed up cause i cant code
also the indents may be of on here :3 anyone knowhow to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The `+ amount` will not do anything. It will just enter `@user 4` if the number they gave in was `4`. If you wanted to do it so that it spammed the user via mentions in 4 seperate messages, this is how you should go through with it:

```py
@commands.command(
    name="ping",
    description="boom boom boom",
    usage="<user> <amount>",
)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def ping(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, amount=15):
    if amount is None:
        await ctx.send('listen here bud your lucky this exists but you\'re the reason that there\'s instuctions on conditioner bottles, specify a user')
    else:
        for i in range(amount):
            await ctx.send(f'Pinging {member.mention} for the {i} time.')
```

In the end, this should send something a bit like this:

```
Me: .ping @user 5

Bot: Pinging @user for the 1 time
     Pinging @user for the 2 time
     Pinging @user for the 3 time
     Pinging @user for the 4 time
     Pinging @user for the 5 time
```

Comment: thank you this will help me with alot more besides just this cmd

Comment: You're welcome. If this helps, do you mind upvoting and accepting? Thanks!